# Stop SQL query execution from .net Code

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, execution

I'm executing one stored procedure from the '.net' code. Since there is a lot of data, it is taking too much time to execute. Is there any way to stop this execution from the c# code?

In other words, if we execute the query from database itself, there is a option to stop its execution but in the code is it possible?

Comment: Can you Add filters in your Stored Procedure? Try to read more about sql best practices..

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Yes sqlcommand.cancel is your friend http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.cancel.aspx

Comment: Apparently closing the command is more likely to work 100% of the time: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/889102/how-to-cancel-a-long-running-database-operation/3699391#3699391

Answer (score 11):

Yes, you can cancel the query by using `SqlCommand.Cancel`. However, the command must be running in another thread (otherwise Cancel will be called only after the command is finished).

Also you can specify a `CommandTimeout` if you want to cancel this query when it runs over a specified time limit.

Comment: the command must be running in another thread  ? real world sample ?

Comment: FWIW, setting the `CommandTimeout` doesn't cancel the query on the database server for MySQL. It just ends the waiting in the client. This needs to be called explicitly @ [MySql Connector/Connection.cs](https://github.com/mysql/mysql-connector-net/blob/5864e6b21a8b32f5154b53d1610278abb3cb1cee/Source/MySql.Data/Connection.cs#L681).

Answer (score 1):

You can do `myCommand.Cancel()`, and this will work best as even i have face similar issue in past, and using `myCommand.Cancel()` i have solved my issue. :) :)