# How to exit an function which is running when I click another one

Tags: c#, asp.net

This is an example function. How could I exit this function to run another one when it is running？

```
public Dictionary<long, int> GetCommitByDays(string username, int queryDays)
{
    /*0 means today */
    queryDays--;
    Dictionary<long, int> commitNumber = new Dictionary<long, int>();
    SqlConnection conn = connectLocaldb.ConnectDataBase();           
    conn.Open();           
    SqlCommand querySingleInfo = conn.CreateCommand();
    querySingleInfo.CommandText = "SELECT CONVERT(varchar(12), CommitTime, 111) as querydate, COUNT(CONVERT(varchar(12), CommitTime, 112)) as queryTimes FROM MemberCommitBeforeCompiling  where UserName='xiehongguang' and DATEADD(d,-"+queryDays+", CONVERT(varchar(12), getdate(), 112)) <= CONVERT(varchar(12), CommitTime, 112)  group by CONVERT(varchar(12), CommitTime, 111) order by CONVERT(varchar(12), CommitTime, 111)desc";
    SqlDataReader singleInfoReader = querySingleInfo.ExecuteReader();
   /*.....*/
    singleInfoReader.Close();
    conn.Close();
    return commitNumber;
}
```

Comment: [This might be helpful: Stop SQL query execution from .net Code](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4779679/stop-sql-query-execution-from-net-code)

Comment: This function is running in back end ,How could I tell it another function will run