# Stop SQL query/Stored Procedure execution

Tags: c#, sql-server, stored-procedures

I am a newbie working on SQL DBA projects,
In order to test SQL server HA/DR i am developing a small C# app.

I got a Button which execute a stored procedure( inserting 1 million rows in to the database).

I got a second Button on which As soon as i clicked on the second button. the execution of the above stored procedure should stop immediately, So that i can start/test my HA/DR procedures.

The code is as below

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    String query = "Execute SP_Details";
    String mycon = "Data Source=localhost; Initial Catalog=Test_Db; Integrated Security=true";
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(mycon); con.Open();
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(); cmd.CommandText = query; cmd.Connection = con; cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    //Label1.Text = "New Registration Successfully Saved"; TextBox1.Text = "";

}

private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ***WHAT SHOULD I WRITE HERE SO THAT I CAN STOP THE ABOVE QUERY/SP***
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Stop SQL query execution from .net Code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4779679/stop-sql-query-execution-from-net-code)

Answer (score 0):

First of all, your SqlConnection and SqlCommand needs to be global (accessible to the second function).

Once that is done, you can use cmd.[Cancel()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.cancel(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: How to do them global ?

Comment: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/2e969c86-69b9-46e4-90fe-3071407b4e87/is-there-any-way-to-declare-a-global-variable-in-c?forum=csharplanguage