# Cannot cancel a background worker running a SQL query

Tags: vb.net

I have searched SO and Google but I cannot find the information I am seeking which may indicate I am not using Background Workers correctly. In my case, I am running a SQL query in a Background Worker so the GUI does not freeze for the user. Please note, supportscancellation is set to true.

However, I am trying to stop the background worker if the user wants to cancel the query. Because my background worker does not have a loop, I am unsure how to accomplish this.

My background worker simply looks at a boolean to determine the type of SQL query, then makes a call to another event to run it.

```
Sub BackgroundWorker1DoWork(sender As Object, e As System.ComponentModel.DoWorkEventArgs)
        If Psearch = True Then
            P_Search()
        End If
        If Asearch = True Then
            A_Search()
        End If
        If Msearch = True Then
            M_Search()
        End If
        If Dsearch = True Then
            D_Search()
        End If
    End Sub
```

Based on articles I find, it seems adding an if statement to check for cancellationpending is irrelevant as it would only fire the one time (at the start of the RunWorkerAsync). So, I have tried using a For/Do loop to check for cancellationpending or workercompleted but it still will not cancel and dispose of the background worker. I have validated this by attempting to restart the background worker but I am erroring out due to workser isbusy.

```
Sub Button7Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
        If backgroundWorker1.IsBusy() Then
            backgroundWorker1.CancelAsync()
            backgroundWorker1.Dispose()
        End If
End Sub

Sub D_Search()  
        Dim sqlConnection1 As New SqlConnection(GlobalConString)
        Dim cmd As New SqlCommand

        cmd.CommandText = RealQuery
        cmd.CommandTimeout = 0
        cmd.Connection = sqlConnection1 
        sqlConnection1.Open()

        Dim daQuery As New System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter(cmd)
        Dim dsQuery As New DataSet

        Try
            If backgroundWorker1.CancellationPending = False
                daQuery = New System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter
                daQuery.SelectCommand = cmd
                daQuery.Fill(dsQuery, "Query")
                tblQuery = dsQuery.Tables("Query")
            Else
                backgroundWorker1.Dispose()
                sqlConnection1.Close()
            End If  

        Catch Err As System.Exception   
            MessageBox.Show(Err.ToString)
        Finally
            sqlConnection1.Close()
        End Try     
    End Sub
```

Comment: Wheres the handles clause from the dowork method? Also you should be checking if the background worker is being canceled in the do work so you can get out...

Comment: The handles clause is in the designer.vb area (I am using SharpDevelop). As stated, I have tried multiple versions of checking for cancellation pending inside of the do work method but nothing seems to work.

Comment: When the above code is run, do you get any errors or exceptions?

Comment: @preciousbetine: The worker executes and completes just fine and I can run additional searches if the workercompleted event has fired. Button7 gives no errors. But, if I try to run an additional search after button 7, I get an error that the worker is busy. I understand that I have to check for cancellation pending inside of the dowork event but as I stated, since the true work is happening in one of the search methods, I don't see a viable way to check for cancellation pending inside of the dowork method. I added a do loop to check for cancellation pending but I end up with the same error.

Comment: `CancelAsync` simply sets the `CancellationPending` property to true, [that's really all it does](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System/compmod/system/componentmodel/BackgroundWorker.cs,ce02087173e2d882). This signals you that a cancellation is requestion so _you_ can act based on that. That means that _you_ (i.e., your code) are the one who's responsible for implementing/executing the cancellation logic (e.g., by exiting a method, breaking a loop, etc.). Now since we can't see your `_Search()` methods, we can't tell you how to "cancel" them or if they're even cancellable.

Comment: @AhmedAbdelhameed: I have added my search method to the original post. Does this help? Obviously the if statement i added does not work. I just placed it there to illustrate i understand what needs to happen (vaguely).

Comment: Is it the SQL query which is taking long enough to give the user time to request a cancellation? Can you do without the datatable? If the answer to both is yes, you could make use of the [SqlCommand.BeginExecuteReader Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.beginexecutereader?view=netframework-4.7.2).

Comment: @AndrewMorton: Yes, the SQL query is what is taking the time to complete. No, I need the datatable because this displays about 5 columns of data that I need to see. Once I see the data, I click any of the rows to expand more data into a flowlayoutpanel with a more succinct/direct query that is instant.

Comment: Don't think you can do with with the DataAdapter. See [Stop SQL query execution from .net Code](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4779679/719186).

Comment: @ClassifiedMystery You can populate a datatable yourself instead of using the built-in but inflexible dataadapter.

Comment: Thank you all for your comments. I was able to resolve this! It appears that I was able to call .cancel on my SQL command. I just made it a global variable so that I can cancel it via button7. @LarsTech, you can cancel a dataadapter as long as the dataadapter is using the SQL command as mine is doing. Thanks!

Comment: If you would like to post the SQL cancel method as an answer, I will happily upvote.

Comment: It's worth noting that the `DataTable` class has a `Load` method that will populate it with the contents of a data reader.  That way, you get your `DataTable` and the ability to cancel an asynchronous query. Of course, if reading the data takes a long time as well as executing the query then you still can't cancel the `Load` call. You'd have to read the data from the data reader and populate the `DataTable` manually for that.