# stoping insertion of record from IIS

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis-8

I have website hosted on IIS
I uploaded excel and it started inserting data to SQL
it is inserting fine  but it is taking too much time I want stop this insertion now

As per my understanding my request is alredy hit to application pool and it is executing from there

If I stop my website it stops the insertion but if I start website it star insertion again ...

Not sure how should I stop this insertion now

Comment: Disable the user in the database and kill any of their existing sessions.

Comment: See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/889102/how-to-cancel-a-long-running-database-operation) thread for a possible solution using the ADO.NET [SqlCommand.Cancel](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.cancel(v=vs.110).aspx) object.